# load a new xhtml page on the same existing page without loosing the another html components

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, portal

[image]

I have this situation : 
-Eclipse Mars
-Primefaces 6.2
-JSF 2.1
-ibm portal framework
-running on websphere

When I click on the primefaces menuitem to open a new xhtml, I need this new xhtml be opened at the same webpage without loose all the another html existin components. I need just a refresh.

here it is my project :

My main page (xhtml) :

```
<h:body>
        <div id="divMain" style="height:200px">
            <ui:insert name="cabecalho">
                <ui:include src="/_MF/jsf/MainMenu.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </ui:insert>

            <ui:insert name="conteudo">


            </ui:insert>        
        </div>       
    </h:body>
```

MainMenu.xhtml :

```
<h:form id="myFormMainMenu">
            <div id="mainMenu">

                <p:megaMenu orientation="#{megaMenuView.orientation}" style="margin-top:20px" autoDisplay="true">
                <p:submenu label="DI" icon="ui-icon-check">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:submenu label="OPTIONS">
                            <p:menuitem value="Listing" icon="ui-icon-document"
                                ajax="false" action="#{mainMenuMB.listar()}" />
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:submenu>
            </p:megaMenu>

            </div>
</h:form>
```

Another form raised from menuitem listar() :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <ui:composition template="/_MF/jsf/MainPage.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <div id="divListar">
          <h1>User settings.....</h1>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>


</html>
```

Comment: @Kukeltje this topic you sent me works fine with commandLink but it does not work with <p:menuitem action="xxx"...>

Comment: When I click on menuitem it loads the new xhtml but it cleans all the existing html component

Comment: `ajax="false"`does a full refresh... try with ajax in a correct way

Comment: thanks @Kukeltje. it worked with the existing post you sent me and  update on the menuitem tag. And removing ajax="false"

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue was resolved with both items : the link and comments below : added update="content" and removed tag ajax="false"

**it worked as expected with this link** : [How to ajax-refresh dynamic include content by navigation menu? (JSF SPA)](http://How%20to%20ajax-refresh%20dynamic%20include%20content%20by%20navigation%20menu?%20(JSF%20SPA)) `<f:ajax render=":content">` ...

and

**this one : I added update='content'**  and removed ajax="false"

```
 <p:menuitem value="Listing" icon="ui-icon-document" 
                                action="#{mainMenuMB.setPage('Listar')}" update="content"/>
```